# OpenCV local pixel average generating extrange output

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to use python to just compute a local pixel color average, however my output is not at all that.

Image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
image = cv2.imread('perspective.jpeg')
for i in range(image.shape[1]):
    for j in range(image.shape[0]):

        up = image[min(j + 1, image.shape[0]-1), i]
        down = image[max(j - 1, 0), i]
        right = image[j, min(i + 1, image.shape[1]-1)]
        left = image[j, max(i - 1, 0)]

        average = (up + down + left + right + image[j, i]) / 5

        image[j, i] = average
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues that you are observing is due to integer arithmetic overflow while computing the average. The reason of overflow is that the pixels are of type `np.uint8` which when added together, generate result of type `np.uint8` which is not large enough to hold the result of addition.

The solution to this problem is to cast the pixels to a larger data-type before adding them. Then cast the final value back to `np.uint8` before storing back to the result image.
In-fact, casting only one of the values (say `up`) to larger data type will suffice as the rest of them will automatically be upgraded while performing addition.

The corrected code may look like this:

```
image = cv2.imread('perspective.jpeg')
for i in range(image.shape[1]):
    for j in range(image.shape[0]):

        up = np.float32(image[min(j + 1, image.shape[0]-1), i])
        down = image[max(j - 1, 0), i]
        right = image[j, min(i + 1, image.shape[1]-1)]
        left = image[j, max(i - 1, 0)]

        average = (up + down + left + right + image[j, i]) / 5

        image[j, i] = np.uint8(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) as shown in the example below. It will work on any number of channels.

```
im = np.random.randint(0, 256, (5, 5), np.uint8)
kernel = np.array([[0, 1./5, 0], [1./5, 1./5, 1./5], [0, 1./5, 0]])
filt = cv2.filter2D(im, cv2.CV_8U, kernel)
```

For example:

```
im

array([[ 14, 127, 221,  74,   2],
       [132, 251,  88,  19, 215],
       [183, 140,  17,  60,  76],
       [208, 144, 182,  11,  64],
       [183,  89, 217, 131,  23]], dtype=uint8)

filt

array([[106, 173, 120,  67, 116],
       [166, 148, 119,  91,  66],
       [161, 147,  97,  37,  95],
       [172, 153, 114,  90,  37],
       [155, 155, 160,  79,  83]], dtype=uint8)
```

You can choose the border type, I've used the default.